# SSLException when using pubsub and cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to set up Cloud SQL in my project and hence to make it work I installed custom SSL certificates. However, now I cannot connect to PubSub and get this error

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am not sure how to get Cloud SQL to work along with PubSub. Any tips are welcome. Haven't been able to find anything on the internet yet

Comment: Can you include more information about your setup? How did you setup your SSL certs? It's hard to offer any advice without more information.

Comment: I kind of managed to close this with Cloud SQL proxy. But if someone comes looking for an answer, here are the details. I added the Cloud SQL cert to my Java settings, and then was able to connect to my SQL instance with 0.0.0.0/0 SSL only. However, I am guessing this replaced certs of my Java store, because now I could not connect to PubSub.

Comment: If you need SSL connectivity from Java w/o having to manually manage certs you can use this library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory